# How to speed up this curl script and response faster

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, performance, curl

I do have this script to get some variables hitting a server. The point is that is doing it slow and I have to run multiple times same script to get a decent rate of requests. How can I multiply number of threads with this curl script without needing to run it 4 or 5 times?

Also I would like to make it faster and performed, this is original one

```
    while ! grep "TokenException" output.txt > /dev/null
do
echo -e '\n'$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%3N) > output.txt
curl -s -H 'Host: host.com' -H "Cookie: session-token="$SESSION\" -H "x-amz-access-token: $token" -H "x-flex-instance-id: $flex" -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; Nexus 5X Build/N4F26T) RabbitAndroid/3.0.6778.0' -H 'Accept-Language: en-us' --compressed 'https://hostname.com/GetOffersForProvider?serviceAreaIds=16' >> output.txt
if grep -q "OFFERED" output.txt; then
    cat output.txt >> foundb.txt

      ./getlast.bat

    if [ ! -f pageflag.txt ]; then
         /usr/bin/php alert.php
        echo "paged" > pageflag.txt
    fi
sleep 0.05
fi
done
```

I modified to

```
while ! grep "TokenException" output.txt > /dev/null
do
echo -e '\n'$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%3N) > output.txt
curl -s -H 'Host: host.com' -H "Cookie: session-token="$SESSION\" -H "x-amz-access-token: $token" -H "x-flex-instance-id: $flex" -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; Nexus 5X Build/N4F26T) RabbitAndroid/3.0.6778.0' -H 'Accept-Language: en-us' --compressed 'https://hostname.com/GetOffersForProvider?serviceAreaIds=16' >> output.txt
if grep -q "OFFERED" output.txt; then
    cat output.txt >> foundb.txt

  ./getlast.bat

         /usr/bin/php alert.php
sleep 0.05
fi
done
```

Some suggestion to run on multi threading and faster even with sleep or another way to pause for milliseconds instead? Main point is that it should execute ./getlast.bat as fast as possible with variables caught from curl, but it has a time difference between data and getlast.bat execution of 2 seconds, too much

Comment: what's the time to execute curl? `/usr/bin/time curl -s -H 'Host: host.com' ...`. That's your bottleneck. Based on that timing you could think of some algorithm to start reading next result while current request is processed. Moreover, do you have to wait for getlast.bat to execute it again?

Comment: Yes getlast does another curl answer sending data, but I need to enhance times. Can you help with some modification example?

Comment: Try to find what is the slowest process, curl or bat script and comment or edit your question with result.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` itself doesn't support multiple connections/threads and/or resume cancelled/stalled operations.

Use [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) or something similar.

Comment: How can I build it with aria? Some example or code help?

Comment: The link I gave has some examples that you can follow. You can also google for examples.